# creating n structure arguments when n is an integer that we got from user

Tags: c

I have an integer for example n from user. The I created a structure named students and this structure has 4 arguments first name (char) last name (char) id (char) and score (float) after that I want to create n students in this structure s1, s2, s3, ..., sn.

And it's my main problem that I don't know how to do this.

I could do like this without using structure but I'm looking for a way to use structure:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_STR_LEN 80

int main() {
    //creating file
    FILE *students_file;
    students_file = fopen("students_file.txt", "w");
    int students_num;
    puts("How many students do you have ? : ");
    scanf("%d", &students_num);
    struct students
    {
        char first_name[MAX_STR_LEN];
        char last_name[MAX_STR_LEN];
        char id[12];
        float average;
    };
    char first_name[MAX_STR_LEN];
    char last_name[MAX_STR_LEN];
    char id[12];
    float average;

    fprintf(students_file, "number  id  firstname   lastname    average\n");
    for (int i = 1; i <= students_num; i++)
    {
        printf("Please enter student #%d first name : ", i);
        scanf("%s", &first_name);
        printf("Please enter student #%d last name : ", i);
        scanf("%s", &last_name);
        printf("Please enter student #%d id : ", i);
        scanf("%s", &id);
        printf("Please enter student #%d average : ", i);
        scanf("%f", &average);
        fprintf(students_file, "#%d.\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %f\n", i, id, first_name, last_name, average);
    }
    fclose(students_file);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to create n students ...

Then, instead of (re)declaring the members here:

```
struct students
{
    char first_name[MAX_STR_LEN];
    char last_name[MAX_STR_LEN];
    char id[12];
    float average;
};
char first_name[MAX_STR_LEN];
char last_name[MAX_STR_LEN];
char id[12];
float average;
```

Use an array:

```
struct students
{
    char first_name[MAX_STR_LEN];
    char last_name[MAX_STR_LEN];
    char id[12];
    float average;
};

struct students *students = calloc(students_num, sizeof *students);
```

then, use that array with the index (`i`), but be aware of `for (int i = 1; i <= students_num; i++)`, arrays are 0 based in C, you want `for (int i = 0; i < students_num; i++)`

Switch from:

```
scanf("%s", &first_name);
```

to

```
scanf("%79s", students[i].first_name); // 79 to avoid buffer overflows
```

and from

```
fprintf(students_file, "#%d.\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %f\n", i, id ...
```

to

```
fprintf(students_file, "#%d.\t %s\t %s\t %s\t %f\n", i, students[i].id ...
```

But notice that in this case (since you are writing to a file) you don't need to create n students nor a `struct`, this is enough:

```
char first_name[MAX_STR_LEN];
char last_name[MAX_STR_LEN];
char id[12];
float average;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer was so complete.